Django Project not working after Updating Ubuntu to Ubuntu version 24.04
So I updated my Ubuntu from version 22.04 to 24.04 yesterday.
Since then my Django project which was in a virtual environment is not working.
I have Python3, pip3, virtualenv and Django installed which I am able to find in the root but not the virtual environment.
Do I need to delete the already existing virtualenv and create a new one before installing Django?

Welcome to AskUbuntu! You should try creating a new virtualenv and try to run your Django project without deleting the existing one. If it works, you can remove the old one and switch to the new one. Let us know if this doesn't work
